# Ошибка autoload.php после переноса сайта на дргой хостинг

Tags: php, drupal

Перенес сайт на другой хостинг. Выдает ошибку:

Warning: require(/var/www/u797755/data/www/домен.ru/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/u797755/data/www/домен.ru/autoload.php on line 16

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/u797755/data/www/домен.ru/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php74/share/pear') in /var/www/u797755/data/www/домен.ru/autoload.php on line 16

Скопировал папку Vendor из другого сайта, не помогло.

Comment: папку vendor верните назад и запустите `composer dumpautoload -o`

Comment: Как это сделать? Читал про composer, но без понятия где это и как с ним работать